# Watch for expression changes outside of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive:

```
<my-directive data-watched-expression='watchedAttribute1 || watchedAttribute2'> </my-directive>
```

And inside directive template I have:

```
<input ng-readonly="{{watchedExpression}}"/>
```

What would be the best solution to be able to reevaluate the expression, when properties watchedAttribute1 or watchedAttribute2 changes outside of the directive?
If possible, I would like to archieve this without passing these variables to the directive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-readonly` directive takes an Angular expression. Don't use interpolation.

```
<!-- Do this -->
<input ng-readonly="watchedExpression"/>

<!-- Not this
<input ng-readonly="{{watchedExpression}}"/>
-->
```

The  `ng-src`, `ng-srcset`, and `ng-href` directives are interpolated. The other attribute directives take Angular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the help!